# Disable Spotlight Index on 10.8 on Specific Volumes

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight

To switch off indexing in Terminal I use:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
```

This disables it with the `-a` switch across all volumes and the `-i off` part turns "off" the indexing.

If connected to my iMac is the following volumes:

```
/Volumes
  /MacintoshHD
  /BOOTCAMP
  /NAS6TB
```

How do I specifically turn off the indexing service only for `/BOOTCAMP` and `/NAS6TB`? I tried following the instructions in the man page, but they weren't very clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From terminal type:

```
sudo mdutil -i off [mountpoint]
```

If you need to remove the index cache of a network drive that has been stored locally, then use the `-p` flag. Likewise, to remove the local cache of a locally attached volume, use the `-E` flag.

If you want to delete from `/BOOTCAMP` then you would use:

```
sudo mdutil -Ei off "/Volumes/BOOTCAMP"
```

**NOTE:** Quotations around the mountpoint of the volume are unnecessary if there are no spaces in the volume name or mountpoint. Otherwise you would need to use an escape character `\` before each space.

**e.g.** `sudo mdtuil -Ei off /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` for "Macintosh HD"

Answer (score 6):

Open spotlight preferences in **System Preferences** and drag each folder to be excluded into the exclusion list.

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight is a powerful tool for searching results in few seconds. Still if you want to disable, it can be done  using launchctl, with password:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Or, to switch off the indexing, you can follow this command

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
```

Comment: the OP is aware of `sudo mdutil -a -i off` and asked how to disable indexing of a specific Volume.